# Why is Olympic freestyle wrestling completed in a single day?

Tags: olympics, schedule, wrestling

Many sports in the Olympics have their games spread across one or even two weeks. But all matches in the wrestling tournament are completed within a single day.

This would lead to more tired athletes by the final stages, so, why is all wrestling done in the same day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Olympic Schedule planning of RIO 2016](https://www.rio2016.com/en/schedule-and-results).

As you can see there are also other sports like Weightlifting / Taekwondo / Shooting / Judo planned in a single day.

I think this is because of structure and techincal reason planning.